# Kafka Consumer outputs excessive DEBUG statements to console (ecilpse)

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, log4j, kafka-consumer-api

I'm running some sample code from http://www.javaworld.com/article/3060078/big-data/big-data-messaging-with-kafka-part-1.html?page=2, and the kafkaconsumer is consuming from topic as desired, but every poll results in print (to std out) of many debug logs, which I don't want.

I have tried changing all INFO and DEBUG to ERROR (even did a grep to make sure) in `/config/log4j.properties`, in particular setting `log4j.logger.kafka=ERROR`, kafkaAppender, but the problem persists. I referred to [How to configure logging for Kafka producers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773780/how-to-configure-logging-for-kafka-producers), and adopted the solution there, but perhaps the situation is different for consumers?

The DEBUG messages all have a similar format:

```
[Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - Sending fetch for partitions... to broker... (id: 0 rack: null)
```

and are appearing at rate of 10 every second or so (changing poll argument to 1000 or even 10000 doesn't help, I tried)

Would really appreciate any help from any expert. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Not sure if it matters, but I added `BasicConfigurator.configure();` to my main method, to resolve some other error occurring previously that stopped the Consumer from even starting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just modify the logging level of the chatty class (chatty interaction).
Since in your logs you see log entries originating from  `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher` you can simply adjust the logging level for that logger by adding following line to `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher=WARN
```

... or any wider catching logger since these are name spaced:

```
# adjusting logging for entire Kafka
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=WARN
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509324/log4j-basic-configuration in the end, and I know that solution is more general (all classes affected) but thanks for the specific solution too! :D

Comment: I am not sure why, but the example I based my answer from was using slf4j. But funny thing is that, I just used log4j instead then used the logback.xml below and it worked :D!

Answer (score 29):

create new config xml file

> src/main/resources/logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka.common.metrics" level="WARN"/>
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are talking about kafka-console-consumer commands, if yes this is what I did:

```
[training@confluent-training-vm ~]$ cd /etc/kafka
[training@confluent-training-vm kafka]$ grep DEBUG *.properties
log4j.properties:# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.properties:# Access denials are logged at INFO level, change to DEBUG to also 
log allowed accesses
tools-log4j.properties:log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stderr
```

So, you just need to edit `/etc/kafka/tools-log4j.properties` file and remove `DEBUG` (or replace it for exmaple by `INFO` and `WARM` log levels on above line

```
tools-log4j.properties:log4j.rootLogger=INFO, WARM, stderr
```

Comment: Your post helped me. I was experiencing excessive `WARN` non-stop messages from `kafka-console-consumer`, which in turn is using `kafka-run-class`. By running this command, `type kafka-run-class.bat | findstr /sin log4j.properties`, i found that it is indeed using `tools-log4j.properties`, and modifying this line `log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stderr` to `log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stderr` solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution under another question which deals with Kafka producers, but it's essentially the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532152/2380553

So I just run the following 3 lines at the beginning of my program:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("kafka").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```